# I need to more images in this part cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:"Image") can any help me

Tags: ios

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell
cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String)
cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:"Image")
return cell
```

Comment: For starter make an array of images, like let imageArray = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]. And then cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:imageArray[indexPath.row])

Comment: i used the code but still am facing same issue

Comment: Please edit your question with clear explanation of the requirement and issue.

Comment: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell
cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String)
cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:"Image")

Comment: i need to add more images in the place of (named:"Image"

Comment: et cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String) cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:"Image")

Comment: i need to more image in the place of(named:"image") but if i create array of images and if i update my code my app is getting crashed

Answer (score 1):

In your image asset, create new Image set. Then name it as Image2. Make another image set, name as Image3 and so on. Then drag and pull some image into the image set, after that use this code

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"cell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell
cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String)

imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Image")!,UIImage(named:"Image2")!,UIImage(named:"Image3")!]

cell.topCellImg.image = roomImage[indexPath.row]

return cell
```

Comment: I hope I understood what you are trying to achieve correctly

Comment: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"cell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell
cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String)

imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Image")!,UIImage(named:"Image2")!,UIImage(named:"Image3")!]

cell.topCellImg.image = roomImage[indexPath.row]

return cell

Comment: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
"cell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell
cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String)

imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Image")!,UIImage(named:"Image2")!,UIImage(named:"Image3")!]

cell.topCellImg.image = roomImage[indexPath.row]

return cell

Comment: hi, i used this and am not getting what i required

Comment: can u share your work? it's quite difficult to understand the problem from your comments

Comment: imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Image")!,UIImage(named:"Image2")!,UIImage(named:"Image3")!]

cell.topCellImg.image = roomImage[indexPath.row]

return cell         i added above code.then also am not able view my image ..my app is getting crashed

Comment: did u added the new images in assets?and named accordingly as well as shown them to their exact names?

Comment: Yes i added the images in assets .

Comment: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as!
                        TopCollectionViewCell
            cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String)
            
           imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Image1")!,UIImage(named:"Image2")!,UIImage(named:"Image3")!]
            
            cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:imageArray[indexPath.row] as! String)
            
        return cell
        }
    } this is what i have done

Comment: u can upload your work to Github? it's difficult to know the issue over comments

Comment: @user8604412 This line will come in viewDidLoad. Move it :  imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Image1")!,UIImage(named:"Image2")!,UIImage(named:"Image3")!]

Comment: @Sharad Chauhan ,the code is already in ViewDidLoad and then also am getting same problem

Comment: edit and send the issue by picture of your code

Answer (score 0):

1. var topSubcategories = Array<[String:Any]>()
       topSubcategories.append(["id":"1"])

   ```
   for i in 0 ..< topSubcategories.count
   {
       var dict = topSubcategories[i]
       dict["image"] = // assign image here
       topSubcategories[i] = dict
   }
   ```

   This one is to add image key in dictionary of given  Array
2. Reload Your UITableView
3. Update imageView from cell dynamically like you have done for label

Answer (score 0):

Declare an imageArray :

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

In viewDidLoad() :
imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Image1")!,UIImage(named:"Image2")!,UIImage(named:"Image3")!]

In cellForItem :
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TopCollectionViewCell

//Also do optional binding using guard let/ if let
if let titleText = topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as? String {
   cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = titleText
}

cell.topCellImg.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
return cell
```

To test it make `imageArray` of same count you are returning in `numberOfRows` method.

Comment: Am getting same problem ....pls let me know the exact solution....

Comment: You did this much ? Now what is the problem exactly ? getting crash ? which line ?

Comment: I have created this array and steps I have followed ,then also am getting same problem..

Comment: Start talking about the problem.

Comment: Am able to give only one image at this point :cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:"Emergency.png") if i create array of images automatically my app is crashing

Comment: here is my code:else{
            
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as!
            
            TopCollectionViewCell
            cell.topCellTitleLabel.text = (topSubcategories[indexPath.row] as! String)
            cell.topCellImg.image = UIImage(named:"Emergency.png")
            
            
                return cell